# Regular expression to match a specific pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
s = "<X> First <Y> Second"
```

and I can match any text right after `<X>` and `<Y>` (in this case "First" and "Second"). This is how I already did it:

```
import re
s = "<X> First <Y> Second"
pattern = r'\<([XxYy])\>([^\<]+)'  # lower and upper case X/Y will be matched
items = re.findall(pattern, s)
print items
>>> [('X', ' First '), ('Y', ' Second')]
```

What I am now trying to match is the case without `<>`:

```
s = "X First Y Second"
```

I tried this:

```
pattern = r'([XxYy]) ([^\<]+)'
>>> [('X', ' First Y Second')]
```

Unfortunately it's not producing the right result. What am I doing wrong? I want to match X or x or Y or y PLUS one whitespace (for instance "X "). How can I do that?

EDIT: this is a possible string too:

```
s = "<X> First one <Y> Second <X> More <Y> Text"
```

Output should be:

```
 >>> [('X', ' First one '), ('Y', ' Second '), ('X', ' More '), ('Y', ' Text')]
```

EDIT2:

```
pattern = r'([XxYy]) ([^ ]+)'
s = "X First text Y Second"
```

produces:

```
[('X', 'First'), ('Y', 'Second')]
```

but it should be:

```
[('X', 'First text'), ('Y', 'Second')]
```

Comment: How do you define where the trailing boundary is? BTW, look at [`(?i)([xy])\s+(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/JpqWj2/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i came up with this solution:

```
pattern = r"([XxYy]) (.*?)(?= [XxYy] |$)"
```

Comment: With short strings, it is OK. If you have very long strings, you should use [`r"([XxYy]) (\S*(?: (?![XxYy] )\S*)*)"`](https://regex101.com/r/1yOfZv/1). Perhaps, the space is better replaced with `\s`.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like: `<?[XY]>? ([^<>XY$ ]+)`

Example in javascript:

```js
const re = /<?[XY]>? ([^<>XY$ ]+)/ig

console.info('<X> First <Y> Second'.match(re))
console.info('X First Y Second'.match(re))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know which whitespace char to match, you can just add it to your expression.
If you want any whitespace to match, you can use \s

```
pattern = r'\<([XxYy])\>([^\<]+)'
```

would then be

```
pattern = r'\<([XxYy])\>\s([^\<]+)'
```

Always keep in mind the the expression within the () is what will be returned as your result.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that a the whitespace token to match is a single space character, the pattern is:

```
pattern = r'([XxYy]) ([^ ]+)'
```

Comment: For `s = "X First text Y Second"` it produces `[('X', 'First'), ('Y', 'Second')]` but it should be `[('X', 'First text'), ('Y', 'Second')]`